# Github for Windows installing got error "Unable to retrieve application files, Files corrupt in deployment"

Tags: github

I am trying to install Github for Windows.  At the point of downloading 30.6MB of data, I received the following error:

> Unable to retrieve  application files, Files corrupt in deployment"

I've tried doing this several times, but the download is always 30.6MB data and it always shows this error. I am confused.

I have included more details below:

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>       Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
>       Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.269
>       System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
>       dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
>
> SOURCES
>       Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
>                           Server      : AmazonS3
>       Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_1_0_20_2/GitHub.exe.manifest
>                           Server      : AmazonS3
>
> IDENTITIES
>       Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=1.0.20.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f45a2159c87c850, processorArchitecture=x86
>       Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=1.0.20.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f45a2159c87c850, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY
>       * Installable application.
>       * Trust url parameter is set.
>   ERROR SUMMARY
>       Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>       * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>           + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Markdown.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
>           + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>       No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>       There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:00] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:02] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:02] : Installation of the application has started.
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:03] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:08] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
>       * [2012/7/30 22:52:09] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>       Following errors were detected during this operation.
>       * [2012/7/30 23:01:14] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
>           - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Markdown.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(String filePath)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>           --- Inner Exception ---
>           System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
>           - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
>           - Source: 
>           - Stack trace:
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>       No transaction information is available.

Comment: Send an email to support@github.com to report this

Comment: Not working for me too....despite all attemps !

Comment: I've installed GitHub for Windows many times and today it doesn't work for me.  I am getting this reported error.  I wish there was a alternate download.

Comment: 3 years later this is still an issue

Comment: @MatthewLock Take a look at my answer below, it may be a .NET dependency issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your download is simply corrupted. Please try again.

Comment: Probably his firewall that is corrupting the download, if it fails on the exact same spot every time. We have this problem too, and we solved it by tunneling out via a vpn, so the firewall can't see the evil executables we try to download.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by switching browsers and downloading it again. I used IE explore to download it. It works well now.
You can find a discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490229/github-for-windows-installation) in the last answer to the question.

Comment: It magically works. I had allready tried and sucesfully downloaded the file through Chrome,  but the installation still failed. I just opened a IE window, tried to download http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application and the original setup worked just like that.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting an old question here because I think some may experience this same error for a different reason in recent times.  So its quite possibly not that the download is simply corrupt. I had the same issue and downloaded from many sources to vet that and got the same error no matter the network used. It may be an issue with your .NET framework. After a little research and an empirical test, this is what I found.

.NET 4.5 supersedes .NET 4.0 but it does not contain .NET 4.0 as part of the package. When 4.5 installs, it overwrites any binaries it shares with 4.0 but won't fill in any that may be missing from 4.0.

I started with a brand new machine. I installed .NET 4.5.1, attempted a github for windows install and received your error. I uninstalled .NET 4.5.1, installed 4.0, then installed 4.5.1 and successfully reattempted the github for windows install.

Answer (score 0):

Add that problem too, but in my case it was simply the AntiVirus blocking it. Disabled the AV during the update and it worked.

The AV was blocking this file `GitHub.UI.dll` and managed to find it through the detailed installation log. The exact message in the log was

```
File GitHub.UI.dll is not a valid Portable Executable (PE) file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue with my work place firewall device, which is a check point firewall.   We also have a microsoft domain.

I get around it by changing windows IE connection settings so it directly connects to the internet instead of the automatic configuration script, or autodetect settings or proxy.

uncheck all, then press ok, (you could also try to use an encrypted external known good proxy https)

Then paste this http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application Into the url, DO NOT RESTART IE.  (some workplaces re-configure ie at start of ie program)
The downloader will use IE's current LAN settings.  This worked for me when my download would stop at 34 MB like clockwork.