# GitHub for Windows installation

Tags: github

While installing GitHub for Windows, how do I resolve this error:

> An error occurred trying to download 'http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application'.

Log file:

```
    The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.2.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 3.1', phase BuildList
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 3.1':
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.1': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 3.1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.50709'
Setting value '4.5.50709 {string}' for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet40Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50709 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.0.30129': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application'.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is likely an Internet connection issue, either temporary (retry and see if the issue persists).

That is what [this comment suggests](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx#87324).

> After trying again, The error was resolved automatically!

If the issue persists, [this comments](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx#87397) suggests:

> then you can try opening github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application directly in internet explorer and then it should work fine.

However, Internet Explorer is not recommended for that (depending on the version, as it might not support the [deployment strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx) [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) (as opposed to the usual Windows Installer).
A recent Firefox or Chrome should allow a silent installation of GitHub for Windows.

Comment: Internet connection is working fine (Checked thoroughly).
The application downloaded via the second is giving an error:
"Deployment and application do not have matching security zones".

Comment: @djadmin what browser are you using. Can you see if the issue persits when using a latest Chrome? Because with IE... it seems problematic: http://www.hikaruyuuki.com/en/blog/internet-explorer-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-but-firefox-downloader-does.html (in order to support the deployment strategy Click-Once, as opposed to windows Installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx)

Comment: @djadmin Excellent. I have edited my answer to reflect my last comment on the important of choosing the right browser.

Comment: I'm trying in latest Chrome (36) and still getting the security zones error. All the browser does is download the file, why would it have any impact on running it after download? Edit: turns out it was a proxy issue, possibly installer can't read .pac files? I had to turn all proxy settings off in OS settings.

Answer (score 32):

You may use `https` instead of `http` and **Internet Explorer**. That is, open the URL below in **Internet Explorer**. It works for me.

```
https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
```

Comment: I think our intrusion prevention software on our firewalls is what's causing the issue.  However, it doesn't scan https traffic so this worked for me!

Comment: stupid firewall at work was the reason for me, https fixed it. thanks.

Comment: I was using IE and still had the problem, But after using the link you have provided it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. I used Internet Explorer for downloading and it worked. Apparently this is the second time I have used Internet Explorer apart from downloading Chrome. Thanks Internet Explorer :P

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue. It was due to proxy settings for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\REGSVR32.EXE %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WUAUENG.DLL
```

Running the above command did resolve this issue. I got the answer from Stack Overflow question *[How to fix this error while installing GitHub on Windows 7 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283381/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Using a local proxy, my solution was to change the address from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

For some reason, Internet Explorer (and this downloader) failed to resolve `localhost`, while Chrome worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. These are the steps I used to resolve it.

<kbd>.Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or Start -> run. Then
write (userprofile%\Local Settings\Apps) or (%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps).

If the OS is Windows XP use the first one or use the second if the OS is Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Then click OK.

And finally delete the (2.0) folder.

Then run again. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens most probably due to slow Internet or interruption in the connection. This download is done with basic down-loader i.e. it doesn't have feature of pausing and fixing server disconnection like most of torrents have. This software is located on amazon servers and they do have limited no. of tries/attempts to download that software from one computer on particular day.When you try to run the program, it generates request from amazon servers for download. And if amazon servers doesn't allow you to download if number of attempts are failed on particular machine. 
Solution for this problem is wait some period of time say few days and try same procedure with stable Internet connection and it will download without any error.
Thanks for reading the answer, i had tried all those other options but none of them worked so i figured out this might be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for the error is amazon server allocates only one download per system.so try after one day.and another thing is use the same internet provider for downloading.before downloading the app keep open the github account.This thing worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

My installation problem to windows 10 was resolved after killing the Network firewall of my antivirus. This often gives troubles, restricting internet connection.