# Installing GitHub for Windows

Tags: windows-7-x64, github-for-windows

I'm trying to install GitHub for Windows.  I tried installing it the normal way and got this error:

`Application installation did not succeed.  Cannot locate application files on the server.  Contact the application vendor or your administrator for assistance.`

Clicking on `Details...` gave me this:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18034
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_1_0_47_0/GitHub.exe.manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=1.0.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=1.0.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_47_0/msvcp100.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:19 AM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:19 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:19 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:20 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:24 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:24 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/21/2013 8:19:25 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_47_0/msvcp100.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I followed the advice on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490229/github-for-windows-installation) and downloaded [github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application](http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application) with the latest version of Chrome.  When I tried to run it, I got this error:

`Application cannot be started.  Contact the application vendor.`

With this detail:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18034
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/SESA277661/Downloads/GitHub.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=1.0.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\SESA277661\Downloads\GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/21/2013 8:29:33 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\SESA277661\Downloads\GitHub.application has started.
    * [5/21/2013 8:29:33 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/21/2013 8:29:33 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/21/2013 8:29:33 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

From here I'm stuck.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

I'm on a work computer, so there may be some security settings blocking something, but I don't know about all that.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Do you see the same issue with other users on other computers at work? There were issues with GitHub yesterday (https://status.github.com/messages), does the issue persists today?

Comment: I got a different issue today.  The error message says that the server returned 403 forbidden on one of the other files.  When I try to browse to that file, our internal security software tells me that it's a virus so it was blocked...  *sigh* I guess I'll try to get one of our IT guys over to help me out later.  Maybe he can temporarily bypass it or something.

Comment: Apparently the only way to bypass our firewall is to get off the network...  I googled and didn't find an offline installer.  I emailed github support to see if they could give me an installer or the downloaded files in a zip or something.

Comment: Did Github support get back with you? I'm having the same issues on my work machine.

Comment: Yeah.  They said that there is no offline installer.  They're currently developing one, but it's not available yet.  The only solution I could find is to get my computer off the work network and try again.  A Proxy or VPN may work depending on how your network is set up.

Comment: same issue for me, offline installer will be very useful, I tried proxy but no success

Comment: Not an answer per say, but suggest https://www.gitkraken.com/

Answer (score 36):

Setup was stalling at around 85MB for me, after repeated attempts. After trying all these answers with no success, [the one found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445313/11398) is the one that finally worked for me. I canceled, killed dfsvc.exe from Task Manager (I'm using Windows 10), deleted C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0, opened up Internet Explorer (not Chrome or Firefox) and navigated to this exact URL:

```
https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
```

Comment: This was the one that resolved it for me. I'm also a Windows 10 user,!

Comment: Doesn't work for me - also a Windows 10 user. I'm still trying to fix this, it's so annoying. It used to work on Windows 10 for me, too.

Comment: Killing the process (dfsvc.exe) and clearing the contents of the AppData folder seemed to work for me. I then ran the GitHubSetup.exe I had originally downloaded.

Comment: I had success changing the url on the `GitHubSetup.exe`.  From the command line, run the following: `GitHubSetup.exe -url=https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/` then re-run the setup.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem and it turned out that a Web Content Filtering system was getting errors for many of the git client files, some of them are included below.

Spoofed files

```
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/msvcp100.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/sqlite3.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/7za.exe.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/RestSharp.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/git2.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/ReactiveUI.Xaml.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/zh-Hant/Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.resources.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/GitHub.UI.dll.deploy
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/GitHub.exe.deploy
```

Missing Digital Signature

```
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/chromium-pack.7z.deploy
```

Number of contained files exceeds limit

```
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_48_0/PortableGit.7z.deploy
```

I suppose you should contact your network admin and get him to set up exceptions for these files, or even better for the whole http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com. Still, IMHO, this shouldn't be happening. I'll try to get in touch with Github support.

Answer (score 6):

I was just having this same problem, I was able to download the installer but after the installer (GitHubSetup.exe) finished doing it's downloading, the program wouldn't launch, it crashed with an error log.
I'm using Windows 8.1; I have never had any trouble in Windows 7.
So I tried right-clicking and "Run as Administrator", it again did it's downloading thing and then launched just fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Introduction

I have had a similar problem: after 75% of the file was downloaded, it just got stuck.
Then 5 minutes later or so, I've received the exact same error message you did.

### How I've fixed it

As [Geogrgios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2546128/georgios) mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17450695/1929635), you need to add an exception to the firewall.

1. Go to "Control Panel" and click on "System and Security" (make sure that "View by:" is set to "Category" and not to "Large icons" or "Small icons").
2. Choose Windows Firewall (the second option in the right menu). Then, "Allow a program or a feature through Windows Firewall" in the left menu will be displayed, please click on it.
3. Click on "Change settings" to add exceptions.
4. Click on "Allow another program ..", which has gotten enabled, and in the new window click on "Browse..".
5. Choose the "GithubSetup.exe" file, press "Open" and then "Add" and "OK".
6. Run "GithubSetup.exe" and hope for the best.

Better instructions (with screenshots) can be found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/542-windows-firewall-add-remove-exception.html)

Answer (score 4):

I opened Microsoft edge and navigated to:

https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

worked first time !

might also work in internet explorer

got the idea from:
stimpy77

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021657/606724

Answer (score 2):

I too faced a similar issue. The root cause was two fold.
1. Proxy: I was behind a corporate proxy, which prevented me from connecting to the download center.
2. Firewall: I was using a corporate laptop in which Symantec network access control was enabled (Firewall related settings are present here)

I disabled the Symantec network access control and used my personal internt connection to download and install. Did not face any issues after that.

Comment: Arghh... damn McAfee was getting in the way in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just switching to Internet Explorer from Chrome did the trick for me =) I don't know why, but it really helped. After 95%(!!) of the file was downloaded, it just got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kaspersky, disable Protection and Control first. Kaspersky Antivirus deletes all deploy files silently, giving erros like this (from `install.log`):

```
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697211'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application'.
```

Or like this (downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application and launching manually):

```
* [15/09/2015 11:58:50] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Unsuccessfull download at file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/Application Files/GitHub_3_0_5_2/GitHub.exe.manifest.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        in  System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        in System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        in System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        in System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Internal exception ---
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows 10:

1. Kill dfsvc.exe
2. Delete this folder: %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0
3. Type in Internet Explorer: https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, and got the isse like 20+ times while I was trying to intsall the github on my Windows 8 Pro.

Solutions found unknowingly is - Login into the Github account, then download the package, and try to install without logout till the installation complition.

It work for me.. Please try and provide if you have any more better way to handle this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem for me was that my corporate network was blocking the download on the network level. This problem was solved for me by going outside of my corporation's network policies via a personal VPN.

When I tried to download GitHub, the ClickOnce app would install with the following error:

> ERROR SUMMARY
>       Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>       * Activation of C:\Users\Judah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc\GitHub.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>
> ```
>     + Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_3_1_1_4/libGLESv2.dll.deploy did not succeed.
>     + Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>     + An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> ```

The error message says it was unable to download `http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_3_1_1_4/libGLESv2.dll.deploy`. Trying to directly download that file with Chrome, IE, and Edge all failed.

I began to suspect it was a corporate network policy that was blocking the download.

So, I connected to a personal VPN, downloaded again, and it worked. You could use a VPN, or tethering on your phone, or some other network outside of your corporate network to download as well.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue when I tried to install it. Even though I'm using VPN I couldn't install it because of network configuration matters. So I turned off the firewall and tried installing it. It didn't work for me in one go coz of some vendor issues and I tried reinstalling it. Finally, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](http://smhow.com/how-to-fix-github-install-for-windows-failure-application-installation-did-not-succeed-cannot-locate-application-files-on-the-server/) post, I just used Internet Explorer and navigated to:

https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

And it completely installed Github for Windows (I have Windows 8.1).

Prior to this, with the installer I downloaded using Chrome I couldn't install Github for Windows (I used to get the above "did not succeed" error).

Answer (score 0):

A little more elaboration on the previous answers:

1- Open Windows Explorer (press "**Windows+E**")

2- Type **%LocalAppData%\Apps** in its address bar and press Enter.

3- It should find a folder "**2**". Delete the Folder "2".

4- Open Task Manager (Start menu, then type Task manager and select it. 
Alternatively press Ctrl+Alt+Delete and select Task Manager).

5- Click on "**Details**" tab.

6- Kill all the files named **dfsvc.exe** (for me there were two).

7- Open Internet Explorer (IE)

8- Paste this address in the address bar and press Enter:

> https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

9- It will start installing Github for Wiindows.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue :

1. Goto `Windows Firewall` => `Advanced` section
2. Goto `Action` > `Properties`
3. set `firwall state` to `off` in domain, private and public.
4. Disable `windows defender` or any other antivirus.
5. Open `run` window by clicking `Windows + R` button
6. Paste "`%LocalAppData%\Apps`"
7. Delete the folder named "2.0".
8. Open `Microsoft edge` or `Internet Explorer`
9. Open "https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application"
10. Click on Install.

This process will be slower than usual but let it run for as long as it takes. And then you should have an Github icon and Shell window icon in your desktop when it ends.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and format your answer.