# Can't install GitHub on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: .net, git, github, windows-7, .net-framework-version

**The current error I am getting:**
*Application validation did not succeed. Unable to continue.*

***Problem Details:***
I had GitHub installed on Windows but I created a new account (paid one) which I decided to use ongoing. I have had GitHub already installed on Windows and was signed-in with the old account.

Yesterday I signed-out from the old account because I wanted to sign-in to the new one. Then after sign-out the App prompted that there's a newer version available for download so I clicked on it to updated the App.
A problem occurred while updating so I uninstalled the App and reinstalled the newer version from this link: https://windows.github.com/

Basically the App will start installing from Amazing servers and when it's downloaded I get this error: *Application validation did not succeed. Unable to continue.*

I tried to remove the content of the "2.0" folder with no luck. I also made sure to provide an exception rule for the installation app inside my Firewall but that didn't help. I also tried to reinstall .Net Framework 4.5 with no luck.

---

**Here's what I get when I click the "Details button":**

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_2_14_7_1/GitHub.exe.manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=2.14.7.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=2.14.7.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Expression.Effects.resources.dll.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:47 PM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:49 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:49 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:50 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:52 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [03/07/2015 12:50:52 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [03/07/2015 12:51:03 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
        - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Expression.Effects.resources.dll.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not GitHub support. Also, did you try downloading it again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about GitHub software installation.

Comment: Hello @JonathonReinhart I don't mind removing this question if it's inappropriate. I only asked it because I found several questions about GitHub on StackOverflow so I thought that isn't an issue. Here's a similar one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671390/installing-github-for-windows

Comment: try the .net framework 4.5.2