# Error Installing GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, windows-10, github-desktop

I have downloaded Github desktop for my win 10 pro x64 from the github site.
Upon running the installation I get the error :

```
"Application cannot be started, contact the application vendor."
```

I tried installing the standlone verison from :

```
https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/standalone/GitHubDesktop.exe
```

but after extraction I got a folder Github desktop,inside which i found the setup.exe.Running it again shows the same error.

I tried downloading the same from IE,but to no avail.I cleared the %temp% folder also,but doesn't helps.Disabled AV while downloading and insatlling,still nothing helps!!

```
%localappdata%
```

Doesn't has the App folder,so cannot do to 2.0 things suggested in other threads(Hidden files are viewable).

I am pasting Log error here:
http://pastebin.com/frTNbtHd

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support team? https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/installing-github-desktop/ at the bottom there is a "contact a human" link that would be useful to you.

Comment: This question is for [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `Run as administrator` when installing?

I've been reading your [Log Error](http://pastebin.com/frTNbtHd) and I found that the reason may be that. It refers an **0x80070005 Error** ([ACCESS DENIED](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968003)).

Comment: I tried doing it now,and i think i am still on the same error.I am pasting the log file again.Please se if you can help!  http://pastebin.com/TUv50U1a

Comment: Have you already tried [this stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671390/installing-github-for-windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact problem as you described the above. I had contacted their support team but found no luck.

Then I tried this way that worked for me...:)

1. Find a person / friend who is having github desktop installed on
   his/her machine.(in my case it was 8.1 X64 bit)
2. Go to "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Apps" this path copy the "Apps" folder.
3. And paste it in your machine's "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local" path
4. Go to
   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\7L52P9YV.Z64\VDMKEAVJ.3ZP\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0002_34b4671ab86a4854"
       this path find "Github.exe".(the folder names may be different in
       yor case).
5. Run the Github.exe
6. Enjoy...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Same or very similar problem for me. Also no `%LocalAppData%\Apps` folder.

Messing with Firewall, AV, running as Administrator - still nothing except endless re-spawning `GitHub Desktop.exe` processes.

My temporary solution:

1. download recent version
2. extract GitHubDesktopSetup.exe with 7Zip
3. then extract GitHubDesktop-0.6.2-full.nupkg navigate to \lib\net45
4. and run GitHub%20Desktop.exe

Seems to work, not tested it other than signing in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file ---> select "troubleshoot compatibility"

----> select "try recommended settings" ----> select "test the program"

if successful then just close the troubleshooter and run the installation like normal
and the problem should be solved.