# How to fix this error while installing GitHub on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: github, installation, windows-7-x64

http://picsmashup.com/images/jnasdh.JPG

> Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) has failed to install with the following error message:
>   "A failure occurred attempting to install the .NET Framework 4 Full."

The following components failed to install:
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\Ck7\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDCD4.tmp\install.log' for more information.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, but I fixed them by following the steps in *[Problem installing .NET Framework 4 (HRESULT 0xc8000222)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/problem-installing-net-framework-4-hresult/bfac5cac-10e8-4eb9-b87d-64a3266522f7)*.

Probably .NET communicates on Windows 7 with a folder named 'SDold' which is named 'Software Distribution'.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command as an administrator:

`%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\REGSVR32.EXE %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WUAUENG.DLL`

Then install .NET Framework 4.5 individually. Then install GitHub. I was having the same issue, and this fixed it for me.