# c# click once deployment after create test certificate

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

so i have c# application that i need  to publish, but then i had to create test certificate to publish it , duo to some expire things. now after that my published app will not work in client machine the error is this "unable to retrieve application files file corrupt in deployment"
 like this image show in client machine [image]

please help.

Comment: Check the AV isn't picking it up, make sure [the .Net framework is installed on the target](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/2781227/-unable-to-retrieve-application-files.-files-corrupt-in-deployment-error-when-you-try-to-start-the-clickonce-version-of-report-builder-from-sql-server-2012-reporting-services) and see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724519/github-for-windows-installing-got-error-unable-to-retrieve-application-files-f)

Comment: i check the .net framework on other machine and it is exists but my target framework is 4 client profile and the other computer version is 4.5 . is this the problem?? . and i am very sorry but English is my second language but what do you mean by AV???

Comment: It [might be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26769607/43846)

Comment: i solved the problem a friend told me to go to properties -> signing tab and unchecked the sign clickonce manifests then save it and publish it again and its worked

Comment: i solved the problem a friend told me to go to properties -> signing tab and unchecked the sign clickonce manifests then save it and publish it again and its worked